# Discard unwanted change set

Tags: tfs

I am looking for a way to discard some unwanted change sets using TFS. I have looked into this site and many other and know that we need to use 
tf merge /version:C137~C137 branch1 branch2 /recursive
However, I store all my source code in TFS DEV environment, I normally check out the code from DEV to my machine, work on it then check it back in DEV, roll back, fix it then check it back in. This process create many different change sets that hang around and needed to be cleaned up. So when I use TF merge command which branch I have to specify DEV and ????.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know about others, but I'm confused. Are you checking in code to two different TFS servers? I don't understand why you check in code, roll it back, check it in again.  Can you try explaining things in a little more detail?

Answer (score 0):

The merge command applies changes from one branch into another. `/discard` option means does not perform the merge operation, but updates the merge history to track that the merge occurred. This discards a changeset from being used for a particular merge.

But according to your description, you don't use branches or merge. What you want is delete/destroy changesets. Unfortunately, you can't delete changesets in TFS by default, if you delete changesets, the version control may be defeated.

You can always work with the latest version, when you want to work on a specific version, you can use `TF rollback` command. This command does not remove the changesets from an item's version history. Instead, this command creates in your workspace a set of pending changes that negate the effects of the changesets that you specify.